# Event Receiver causing issue for Designer Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, event-receivers

Below are my scenario and I need some assistance as to how to create a workaround.

I have a site called Framework. The client has an Event Receiver that sets unique Item Level Permissions.

How it works is if a user adds an item to a list or library the Event Receiver sets unique permissions on the current Item. The permissions it sets is Read Only.

Within this site is a List called Process that I have InfoPath and Designer WFs running.

Since the Event Receiver sets all normal user permissions to Read Only, the WF errors and cancels out. The Event Receiver is set in place to restrict View to employees outside the United States.

To counteract this, using Designer 2013, I created a 2010 WF with a Replace List Item Permissions activity. I have it set to replace the item permissions to Contribute for US employees instead of Reading.

When a user adds a new Item the Event Receiver kicks off and sets unique permissions on the current item. Afterward, my workflow fires (after pausing) to set those permissions to Contribute.

The issue is that after the workflow runs, the Event Receiver goes back and resets the unique permissions back to Read Only for all users. Which then cancels out all other workflows as a minimum of Contribute is required.

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place. Can you help with suggestions? Is there anything I could do with Designer to counteract this?

Comment: I would implement everything in an Event Receiver or in a workflow, both is just a mess. I would say try ditching the ER and use a custom permission to give the non-US employees Add Items and Read privs. That would be cleaner I think.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The whole thing is just a mess. When you say to ditch the ER and use a custom permission, are you referring to setting custom permissions via a workflow?

Comment: No, I'm saying use a custom permission on the list itself, where users can only add and read items, then there is no potential for them to edit items and then not need to do any permissions breaking

Comment: Yes I do have permissions on the list itself. The issue is the ER that sets unique permissions on any item a user creates on the list. I think I can copy the current item into a folder and that might work. I followed this article http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-sharepoint-rest-services-from.html. The issue is it's not working for me. Have you ever tried to move a current item in a list to a folder within the same list?